# Other option to trigger javascript function

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have the following javascript function which works nicely on a single html file.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function() {
    $('#focus-init').click(function() {
        $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', 1, 0, 0);
    });
});
```

The issue appears when I try to integrate the above function into my wordpress theme. It seems that any other page I browse the above function is always called which I don't expect it to happen.

Since the #focus-init only exist on one page how can I specify that the above function should only be called when the element ID is found ?

**UPDATE**

I am afraid this wordpress theme does not have a concept of page title, since any other page has the same title tag

Comment: this code should be added to only the targeted page.. not to every page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery(function() {
    if ($('#focus-init').length !== 0) {
        $('#focus-init').click(function() {
            $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', 1, 0, 0);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: i'd also recommend using the `on` event binding. `$('#focus-init').on("click", function() {`, as this doesn't require the item to exist when the binding is created DOM element that is

Comment: @abc123 You like that delegation, don't you?

Comment: Yeah, it does require a newer jQuery version though so that is one of the negatives